# Selecting an SVG Circle with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dom, svg

I have a very simple SVG `<circle>` element in my DOM that I want to select with TypeScript:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" id="myCircle"/>
</svg>
```

---

### First attempt:

I try to select the circle as follows:

`var circle: SVGCircleElement = document.getElementById("myCircle");`

but I get the error:

> Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties: cx, cy, r.

Ok, fair enough. So I try type-assertion:

### Second attempt:

`var circle: SVGCircleElement = (<SVGCircleElement>document.getElementById("myCircle"));`

and I get the error:

> Conversion of type HTMLElement to SVGCircleElement may be a mistake because...

This method of selecting elements seems to work with other elements, such as a `<canvas>` but not for SVGs:

[image]

### Question:

What is the TypeScript-approved way of selecting `myCircle` from the DOM, preferably without resorting to type coercion? (By the way, I'm using Typescript 3.3)

Answer (score 2):

this is atleast one way is to define typeguards which allow you to prove to typescript that is indeed a circle, there is no "best way" it really depends on the use case but i feel like this is a stronger approach to casting.

```
const isHTMLCircle = (something: HTMLElement | SVGCircleElement): something is SVGCircleElement => {
    if(!something) return false;
    return something instanceof SVGCircleElement;
}

const getSvgCircleById = (id: string): SVGCircleElement | null => {
    const element = document.getElementById("id");
    if(!element) return null;
    if(isHTMLCircle(element)) {
        return element;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: So the only way to do it is by still casting to the `<any>` type? I'm surprised TypeScript doesn't have a built-in way of doing this...

Comment: you don't need to cast i'll edit snippet and no there is nothing built in that let's you do this because there is no getSvgById in javascript, getElementById can't possibly know through static analysis the type of the element you're trying to get.

Comment: Iv'e added a edit with a getSvgCricleById function that allows you to get a SVG circle type back there is no casting to any

Comment: Darn... that's a lot of code for a simple element selector. I think I'll stick to `myCircle: SVGCircleElement = <any>document.getElementById("myCircle");` I appreciate your help, though!

Comment: the problem with casting is that it doesn't handle the case of it the element at id "myCircle" wasn't actually a circle but you've lied to typescript and told it it is a circle.

Guards give you a way to prove something is indeed a circle